# Проблемы с определением длины промежутка

Tags: c#, логические-выражения

Делаю программу для решения 15 задания ЕГЭ.
Я написал код, который должен определить длину промежутка, но возвращаемое им значение меньше ответа.

**Задача:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Мой код:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace EGE_15
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x, a1, a2; // a1 - начало промежутка, a2 - конец 

            List<int> answers = new List<int>(); // Все подходящие промежутки

            for (a1 = 0; a1 < 100; a1++)
            {
                for (a2 = 0; a2 < 100; a2++)
                {
                    bool z = true; // Переменная для проверки промежутка при любом "х"
                    for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)
                    {
                        if (f(x, a1, a2) == false)
                        {
                            z = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (z == true)
                    {
                        answers.Add(a2 - a1);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(answers.Max());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool f(int x, int a1, int a2)
        {
            return !((5 <= x && x <= 30) == (14 <= x && x <= 23)) || !(a1 <= x && x <= a2); // Формула из задачи с применением правила логики (А → В = !А || В)
        }
    }
}


//P = [5, 30] и Q = [14, 23]
//    ((x ∈ P) ≡ (x ∈ Q)) → ¬(x ∈ A)
```

После его работы, ответ получаемый им - 8, а нужно получить 9

---

Я пробовал использовать код для другой подобной задачи и ответ, который я получил, подошел к ответу с сайта

**Код такой же, но с изменённой функцией f:**

```
        static bool f(int x, int a1, int a2)
        {
            return !((a1 <= x && x <= a2) || (25 <= x && x <= 50)) || (!(a1<=x&&x<=a2) || (32<=x&&x<=47));
        }
```

**Задача:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Либо вы не правильно понимаете выражение "длина промежутка", либо в приведенном Вами примере ЕГЭ ошибка. В примере написано, что правильный ответ либо [5;14) либо (23;30]. Обратите внимание на круглые скобки. То есть 14 и 23 в ответ не входят. И если речь идет о множестве целых чисел, то правильный ответ можно записать как [5;13] или [24;30]. Их длины - 8 или 6, соответственно. А если считать в количестве возможных чисел, то 13-5+1=9 либо 30-24+1=7. В Вашем коде число 14 не подходит, что правильно. Но получается, что Ваш код возвращает ответ не в виде [a1;a2), а в виде [a1;a2]. То есть, надо прибавить единицу.

Но это если понятие "длина промежутка" эквивалентно понятию "количество целых чисел в промежутке". Если по другому, то ответ я не знаю. :)

Comment: По идее промежутки [5;14] и [5;14) или (5;14) имеют одинаковую длину, но как сделать так, чтобы моя программа понимала это - непонятно

Comment: Если промежутки на множестве целых чисел, то нет, длины разные. Интервал [5;14] - это последовательность 5, 6, 7 ... 13, 14. Интервал [5;14)===[5;13] - 5, 6, ... 12, 13, интервал (5;14)===[6;13] ... ну Вы поняли. И длина у них будет разная. Еще раз повторюсь - надо определиться с понятием "длина". И если "длина" - это количество элементов в интервале, тогда длина интервала [a1;a2] определяется как a2 - a1 + 1. Подчеркну жирным "+1". Простой пример. Возьмите интервал [1;1] - какая у него длина - 0 или 1?

Comment: Если считать по количеству элементов, то 1. То же самое у Вас. Правильный ответ (если из объяснения) - [5;14) === [5;13]. На множестве целых чисел в него входит 9 элементов. " как сделать так, чтобы моя программа понимала это" - никак. Это ВЫ должны зашить логику алгоритма в код. То есть написать - answers.Add(a2 - a1 + 1);